# Text alignment in the table

Tags: tables, align, tabularx

I have increased the height of the rows in the table, and now I have a question how to make the text (УТВЕРЖДЕНО, РАЗРАБОТАНО, СОГЛАСОВАНО) in these rows in the center of the rows?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
 Фамилия Инициалы  & Должность & Дата & Подпись \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{УТВЕРЖДЕНО} \\ [2ex] \hline
 1.   &  &  &\\ \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{СОГЛАСОВАНО}  \\ [2ex] \hline
 2.  &  &   & \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{РАЗРАБОТАНО} \\ [2ex] \hline
 3.   &  &   & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: try replace `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{СОГЛАСОВАНО}  \\ [2ex] \hline` with `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\parbox[c][5ex][c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}{\centering СОГЛАСОВАНО}} \\ \hline`

Comment: Your code is not compilable since you use personal commands. Could we a complete code?

Comment: @Lucky_girl you mean vertical alignment? You could use `\multirow` package.

Comment: *A priori*, the simplest is to use the `cellspace` package, which defines a minimal vertical padding around cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `\rule` of zero width and `4ex` height (`\rule{0pt}{4ex}`) to these three headings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
    \hline
 Фамилия Инициалы  & Должность & Дата & Подпись \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{УТВЕРЖДЕНО\rule{0pt}{4ex}} \\ [2ex] \hline
 1. \approverPost{}  & \varApprover{} & \varDateapprove &\\ \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{СОГЛАСОВАНО\rule{0pt}{4ex}}  \\ [2ex] \hline
 2. \visantPost{} & \varVisant{} & \varDatevise{}  & \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{РАЗРАБОТАНО\rule{0pt}{4ex}} \\ [2ex] \hline
 3. \initiatorPost{}  & \varInitiator{} & \varDatecreation{}   & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```